# for loop not running inside single value event listener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement a search feature where, upon clicking on the search result, I display the user's details in a fragment. The problem is in the `init()` function where the foreach loop inside the `onDataChange()` funcion doesn't execute.

```
private User mUser;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_profile, container, false);

    try{
        mUser = getUserFromBundle();
        init();
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: NullPointerException: "  + e.getMessage() );

        setupFirebaseAuth();

        return view;
}

private void init(){

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.db_user_account_settings)).orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).equalTo(mUser.getUserid());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                UserSettings settings = new UserSettings();
                settings.setUser(mUser);
                settings.setSettings(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class));
                setProfileWidgets(settings);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}

private User getUserFromBundle(){

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        return bundle.getParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_user));
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="field_user_id">user_id</string>    
    <string name="intent_user">intent_user</string>    
    <string name="db_user_account_settings">user_account_settings</string>  
</resources
```

I have no idea why this isn't working.

---

From comment:

[image]

> 1), 2) I've added the strings.xml code you can refer to 3) The blue arrow in the screenshot shows the userid that is returned (which is exactly what I want) 4) The red portion is what I'm querying 5) Yes. I'm a bit new with JSON and firebase,

Comment: What does `.getChildren()` return?

Comment: "it seems the for loop doesn't execute" I'm not sure what this means. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger. If you put a breakpoint on `for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){` and run in a debugger, does it reach that line? If not, does your `onCancelled` get called. Note that the minimum implement of `onCancelled` is: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. Anything else ignores potentially errors.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes. The debugger reachers the line, but the code inside doesn't execute.

Comment: That means that there are no children matching the query. Here too: please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a very inefficient debugger, and read the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase the chances we can help. Things missing: 1) What is the value of `getString(R.string.db_user_account_settings)`? 2) What is the value of `getString(R.string.field_user_id)`, 3) What is the value of `mUser.getUserid()`? 4) What JSON are you querying? 5) Did you implement `onCancelled` as I suggested?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://imgur.com/QEKvPAF). I've edited the question so that it's more understandable and descriptive. 1), 2) I've added the strings.xml code you can refer to 3) The blue arrow in the screenshot shows the userid that is returned (which is exactly what I want) 4) The red portion is what I'm querying 5) Yes.      
     
I'm a bit new with JSON and firebase, I hope you understand. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any ideas?

Comment: @Aniox .getChildren() is returning null. That shouldn't happen since I do have [children](https://imgur.com/QEKvPAF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does:

```
reference.child(getString(R.string.db_user_account_settings)).orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).equalTo(mUser.getUserid())
```

Which translates to:

```
reference.child("user_account_settings").orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(mUser.getUserid())
```

So it:

1. Takes all child nodes under `user_account_settings`.
2. Orders them on the value of their `user_id` property.
3. Selects only the nodes where that value exists and is equal to the UID.

Since the JSON you showed doesn't show a `user_id` property, there are no results.

If you have the value you are looking for as the key of a node, you can just use `child(...)` to look that node up. And since there can only be one child node with a given key, that means you no longer need the loop over `getChildren()` in the `onDataChange` method.

So something like:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.db_user_account_settings)).child(mUser.getUserid());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserSettings settings = new UserSettings();
        settings.setUser(mUser);
        settings.setSettings(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class));
        setProfileWidgets(settings);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Frank!